# PhpStorm indicating Laravel route injection in JavaScript as error

Tags: javascript, laravel, phpstorm

[image]

Does anybody knows why PhpStorm is indicating ajax URL as an error?

Because I mostly used it this way and it works. When I updated PhpStorm to 2021 latest version it shows this as an error or bad practice. Please guide.

[image: layzOne as you have asked a picture]

[image: here is second one which is taken by on hovering error indicator]

Comment: 1) What is the actual error being reported? 2) Can you share that file (as a file to download) so it can be tested locally. You can redact company name or other private info but please leave the overall structure intact.

Comment: Also: 3) Place caret there in such JavaScript fragment (e.g. in a place shown on your screenshot where the caret is) and invoke Quick fix/light bulb menu (`Alt+Enter` on Windows) and show what menu you will see.

Comment: @LazyOne please check I have added some more images as you have asked

Comment: @LazyOne There is nothing more in the file its just looping log files, actually this blade file is working fine, all functions are working there is no error when Open this view in my software,  it's just phpStorm indicating that URL:`{{route()}}`, area as error by show that red underline,  after update to a newer version of 2021,

Comment: Sorry, I've suggested all I could by looking at the screenshots. Perhaps I can spot something if I play with the actual file here on my PC... Right now I do not understand why comma after `"POST"` is highlighted, why syntax colors are lost for the rest of the structure  -- after `url`...

Comment: @LazyOne  here is the link you can download the file 
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NJDyJz23NJzZecbFhsT10Ryni8s2mf5R

Comment: This has to be some bug in Blade plugin (how it handles `{{ }}` tags in injected fragments / inside `javascript` section -- the JS is auto injected inside it)). I suggest you report it to PhpStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI for devs to look into. [My search](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPHP%20Templates%7D%20blade%20javascript) could not locate a ticket with a similar issue.

Comment: @LazyOne I have reported this issue on youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI  here is the link to  it
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-63851?clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0APS-212.5457.49,%20JRE%2011.0.12%2B7-b1504.40x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o.,%20OS%20Windows%2010(amd64)%20v10.0%20,%20screens%201280.0x1024.0